# If you gain your rep by asking questions, are you still a valid answerer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different types of reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/different-types-of-reputation)

I gained most of my rep by asking good questions about things I'm having trouble with. Does this mean I'm inexperienced and you shouldn't trust my (or someone like me to) answer(s) to your questions?

Comment: Please don't ask opposite questions in the title and the question body.  I don't know which one to answer. :)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/different-types-of-reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking good questions is a good way to learn, for everybody - one of the site's concepts.

Sometimes even, you can answer a similar question just by pointing to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are a valid answerer.  It takes critical thinking and judgment to ask a good question, and expertise to ask a great one.