# Remove sponsored tag logo from Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

I'm not sure if this falls under [sponsored tag bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23965/ignoring-sponsored-tags-doesnt-work) fix, but I've placed the the adobe tags in my ignored list and still receive the logo on the sponsored tag.  If the tag is in my ignored list, I'd prefer to not see the icon as well.

I can just imagine stackoverflow down the road....

[image: picture with some icons in the ignored tag section... or something like that]

**Edit** - As a work around, the icons can be ignored via [wild carding the ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23965/ignoring-sponsored-tags-doesnt-work/23969#23969)

Comment: +1 for hash icon ... Perhaps that's why it keeps forgetting the values I give it...

Comment: +1 for "hash", but -1 for no "cucumber".

Comment: I'm pushing the "add" button to it but its not working :(

Answer (score 13):

I disagree with Jeff Yates. Showing an Adobe logo to someone who has specifically ignored Adobe tags is not effective advertising. In fact, it only serves to foster resentment - making it less likely that the user will take interest in the sponor's product in the future.

I agree that the logo-free tag should appear in the ignore list. However, I don't expect this would be a high priority for the team.

Answer (score 4):

yes, and I still see questions with the flash tag even though flash is in my ignore-list and I don't show ignored questions.

I find this sponsored tag thing extremely annoying, I don't want my user experience trashed with all kinds of unmatching colors and shapes.

Comment: @tharkun - it's fixed and will get pushed tomorrow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23965/ignoring-sponsored-tags-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this would really be helpful to StackOverflow. After all, they are being paid to advertise their sponsor and even if you want to ignore the tags, I don't think it's fair to allow you to ignore the advertising too.

You can't eat a free lunch and then complain that someone wants to try to sell you something while you eat it.

Comment: If you're not interested in that product, by adding it to your ignore list, you're not in their target market anyway.

Comment: Isn't everybody in Adobe's target market?

Comment: However Alex has stated that the majority of users come from google and don't use ignored tags, so really it won't hurt SO that much.

Comment: "I don't think it's fair to allow you to ignore the advertising too." I'm sorry, but nobody is gonna tell me what I can or can't ignore! It would be unfair if they would.

Comment: @fretje: Come on now, that's not what I meant and I think you know that. I meant ignore in terms of the "ignored tags" feature, not the actual act of ignoring. if you choose to physically ignore the advertising, that is indeed your choice, but you can't blame a site for wanting ad revenue.

Comment: @random: Yes, I can see your point, but if we all had great ways to block advertising, we wouldn't get any - even the stuff we might find useful, and then, awesome free stuff like SO would vanish.

Comment: @Jeff: You said "I don't think it's fair to allow you to ignore the advertising." I meant "I don't think it's fair to *not* allow you to ignore the advertising."

Comment: @fretje: Within in the context of this site...not your entire life. What you choose to ignore is up to you, but I don't think the site has a responsibility to make it easier for you.

Comment: @Jeff: I *am* talking within the context of this site. As this site is run by the community, it's this site's responsibility to please this community. Let the "daily Google click-through traffic" (which is much bigger than the community anyway) watch and click on the ads, but I don't think the active community itself should be put up with them. They're creating the content for crying out loud!

Comment: @fretje: We have to encourage people to actually participate, not run them off with annoying advertising. What is good for the goose is good for the gander and just because we provide the content doesn't mean we can demand that their revenue sources can be duly ignored. The community creates the content for the love of their craft.

Comment: @Jeff: Then I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with that picture.  It helps me visually group related tags together.  And I think lots of icons is actually *less* visually jarring than just a few.  Otherwise, the few look really out of place.

That said, I think this makes sense.  If you're ignoring a tag, you probably don't need to see a logo right there.  The only reason not to do it is that it probably means added extra code clutter for the special case.  As mere *users* of the site that's not really our problem (though I do understand that it might be a *long* while before the time has time to make that change).

There's also the thought that *if* this becomes common, omitting the icons from the ignored tags actually *looks* like a bug at first glance.

Comment: is `$('#ignoredTags .post-tag').children().remove()` a lot of code clutter?

Answer (score 3):

Greasemonkey FTW

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Tag img remover
// @namespace      remove_img_from_tags
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com//*
// ==/UserScript==

$('#ignoredTags .post-tag').children().remove()
```

Comment: I confess that for a long time I though FTW meant "F* the What!", ie WTF backwards so it was something good instead of bad.  Now I know better, but I still like my alternate interpretation.

Comment: @Joel: Don't feel bad. When I first saw it, I thought it meant "F**k the world", like you were just giving everyone a big middle finger or something.

Comment: Now I have the image of a greasy monkey humping planet earth... Thank yoiu very much gnovice!

Comment: That's what I'm here for!

Comment: Humping the world?

Comment: @Jeff: Putting unsavory images in peoples heads is my *job*... humping the world is just my hobby.

Comment: Or if you want to get rid of all of the sponsored tag nonsense in one go: `$('.post-tag img,.welovestackoverflow').remove();`